# polymer not reflecting default properties

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm new to Polymer, and finding the docs pretty sparse. I'm trying to have a custom element styled based on an initial, reflected property value, and no matter what I do, it seems that the reflection isn't working - no attribute appears on my element. Nor does it appear if I set the attribute in code.

```
<dom-module id="so-login">
<style>
    :host {
        background-color: white;
    }
    :host[loggedin] form, :host:not([expanded]) form {
        display: none;
    }
    :host[loggedin] #prompt, :host[expanded] #prompt {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>

<template>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({is:'so-login', properties: {
    expanded: { type: String, default: "Test", reflectToAttribute: true }
}});
</script>
```

```
<so-login></so-login>
```

I'm running this in Chrome & Edge, latest. What am I missing?

Comment: Correct way of writing attribute styles in `:host`, in Polymer, is by surrounding the attribute tag with parenthesis `:host([loggedin])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about the "expanded" attribute, I see no evidence of the "loggedin" attribute in the properties object for the element.

Rather than declare it as a string - declare it as a Boolean inside the properties object.  The default value is set with value:true, rather than default:true (same is true if it were a string).

If it is indeed a string you probably need to include it on the instance of the element thus; `<so-login expanded="">`